# JavaFX: Task will not update UI

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, javafx, task

I'm working on an Omaha online poker client written in javaFX+java.

I need to show an anchorPane containing 3 buttons after `control.call()` finishes executing. **I know for a fact that control.call() finishes executing** but for some reason `task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler() {`'s handle method **does not** update the User interface.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void newRound() {

    sog = StateOfGame.PREFLOP;       

     ControlGameOnNewThread control = new ControlGameOnNewThread();

    Task task = new Task() {

        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            control.call();
            return null;
        }
    };

    task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            if (client.getAction() == FirstToAct.me) {
                System.out.println("Task finsished");
                    showOptions(client.getToCall());
                    opponentBetField.setText(new Integer(opp.chipsInvested).toString());
                    myBetField.setText(new Integer(client.chipsInvested).toString());
                    System.out.println("Task finsished");

            }
    }
    });


    new Thread(task).start();


}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `call(...)` method is succeeding, rather than throwing an exception? Try registering a `setOnFailed(...)` handler with a `task.getException().printStackTrace()` to see if something being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are updating the user interface in the other thread.. if you are in the other thread and you want to update the user interface

You need to call the

---

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    //Update UI here     
  }
});
```

calling this will call the main thread and update all the necessary update to the user interface

**EDIT**

```
public void newRound() {

    sog = StateOfGame.PREFLOP;       

     ControlGameOnNewThread control = new ControlGameOnNewThread();

    Task task = new Task() {

        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            control.call();
            return null;
        }
    };

    task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {

            if (client.getAction() == FirstToAct.me) {

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                  @Override public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Task finsished");
                    showOptions(client.getToCall());
                    opponentBetField.setText(new Integer(opp.chipsInvested).toString());
                    myBetField.setText(new Integer(client.chipsInvested).toString());
                    System.out.println("Task finsished");     
                  }
                });
            }
    }
    });


    new Thread(task).start();


}
```

Comment: I've tried to implement what you've said but I encounter the same issue. Here is the new code: http://pastebin.com/zcvybKik

Comment: @zeroRooter updated my answer.. what I meant is to only put the user interface update not the class instances

Comment: Thanks for your help so far but the UI is still not updating after implementing your solution, I always thought Platform.runLater() created a new thread anyhow. Anyway, Here is a link to the entire document https://github.com/zeroRooter/Omaha-Poker/blob/master/src/huclient/ClientControl.java (function newRound is on line 310)

Comment: @zeroRooter Where is the new Thread(task).start();? did you put it there?

Comment: Yeah actually it seems i had forgotten it, however the issue still persists, i have git pushed.

Comment: The `setOnSucceeded(...)` handler is actually executed in the FX Application Thread anyway. You don't need a `Platform.runLater(...)` here.

Comment: @zeroRooter, hi did u found the solution for it, me too having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

As you override the `call()` method, you can override the `succeeded()` method: (See last example in the javadoc of Task.)

```
@Override protected void succeeded() {
     super.succeeded();
     updateMessage("Done!");
}
```

`succeeded()` is already called on the JavaFX Application Thread, so you do not need to do this for yourself.

Are you sure, that the code in your handle method isn't called? Maybe a NullPointerException is thrown, which you might not see? Is the comparison working as expected?

Try moving the code with `if (client.getAction()...`  into the overridden `succeeded()` method and put a println before the if-statement in order to see whether it is called or not.

(EDIT: typos)

Comment: Line 347 ish https://github.com/zeroRooter/Omaha-Poker/blob/master/src/huclient/ClientControl.java

Yeah the code definitely is not getting executed, i have done what you said with the println and i've uploaded it to git again. Overriding succeeded should do the same thing as what i'm doing though right?

Comment: @zeroRooter yes - put the if-statement with its block into the overridden succeeded() method. It should do the same. While you are at it, also override failed() and cancelled() and put println statements there too. You should also put a print statement right before the return statement in the call() method. So you can see whether the call method makes it though or gets an exception in between. An exception would be stored in the `exceptionProperty` which you can look at in the `failed()` method.

Answer (score -1):

Your information has been helpful, but i think all methods suggested would have worked (including my initial one). The problem is that the task was never *ended* that's why the onTaskSucceded was never executed. In order to have the task exit after it has finished, i had to se the daemon to true:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
```

Comment: Even if this works, I think it may be hiding some underlying issue with how you are using Tasks.  Whether a task onTaskSucceeded is called really shouldn't be related to the daemon status of a thread.

Comment: Did your "succeeded" code get executed after inserting the call of  `setDaemon(true)` ?

Comment: Yes, but i think that it also gets a little confused if you still leave code that updates the UI on the different thread. In truth, you need to set the Deamon to true AND remove and all code that is updating the UI on any other non-main-javaFX thread.

Comment: As jewelsea mentioned, there is another problem hiding if setDaemon(true) "worked". You need to be careful to only update the UI on the JavaFX Application Thread. You should carefully check your code for UI access in the wrong thread.